# Standard, non-SSL, HTTP encryption

Tags: http, encryption, ssl, embedded, aes

We are putting an HTTP RESTful interface into an embedded platform of ours.  The hardware is too limited to support SSL, but we do use AES encryption for other things.

I'm thinking of using AES with a shared key to encrypt the data.  Is there anything else that is at least a somewhat standard way of encrypting via HTTP?

Comment: In what way is it too limited for SSL?

Comment: I found a similar question with a good response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246831/lightweight-encryption-key-exchange-protocol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way of encrypting HTTP **is** SSL (or its successor TLS, nowadays) (this is then known as HTTPS).

As GregS asked in a comment, in what way is your platform too limited for SSL, but still allows AES? Does it have not enough computing power/memory to do modular exponentiation (which is used in RSA, DSA, Diffie-Hellman)?

Then you might be able to use a pre-shared key version of TLS. [RFC 4279](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4279) defines cipher suites with pre-shared key authentication, where the `TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` looks like if needs only AES and SHA-1, no modular exponentiation.

Of course, you shouldn't use this if there is the danger that an attacker can get the secret (e.g. by cracking your device), since this allows also to read all previously registered connections (in contrast to Diffie-Hellman, which provides a new session key for each session).

Comment: @Craig: Thanks for the edits ... looks like I shouldn't try to answer when I'm tired.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, the modular exponentiation and random number generation is the issue. The RFC you pointed to is exactly what I needed, or at least it gets me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: You will still need random numbers for initialization vectors, I suppose. One can build a PRNG from a block cipher like AES, though. (As an example, see [ANSI X9.31](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/634/58).)

Answer (score 0):

Found this gem: Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange in 10 lines of C
http://www.cypherspace.org/rsa/dh-in-C.html

Comment: I would not really call this obfuscated code a *gem*, though.